# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28 and button isn't seen in design when drag

Tags: android

Here if i drag button, it isn't seen.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

just try it change **CompileSdkVersion** And **minSdkVersion** to 27.
and change this field

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.1'
```

To

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

My problem with this was fixed. I think Do not use version 28 completely.

Answer (score 0):

**Root cause**: The version 28.1.1 does not exist.
**Solution**: Use the latest stable version. If you use this, please don't forget to change the `compileSdkVersion` and `minSdkVersion` field in your `build.gradle` file to **27**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

or use latest unstable version(currently in development):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
```